# Is there a way to share local PostgreSQL between computers?

Tags: django, postgresql

I recently started working on some project with my friends. I'm working on backend with Django, and others do frontend. As they have no knowledge about Django, I was wondering if I can add the db file into the project folder, so that they can use the local db by just pulling the db file from Github repository.

When I used to use sqlite3, I could do this simply having the sqlite3.db file in my project folder. However, PostgreSQL has me use its program to create database, I'm confused how I can get the db file.

Is it possible to have a local PostgreSQL db file in my Django project so that my friends use the db by just cloning the project and installing PostgreSQL in their computers?

Just so you know, I created my Django project with cookiecutter-django.

Comment: No, because Postgres is not a "file". But if you want this, why don't you use sqlite? Django abstracts away the differences anyway.

Comment: Or host a tiny Postgres instance on AWS that is accessed in your settings file?

Comment: @dfundako I was thinking of that. Do you think that's the best way in this case? I just wanted have my friends use the DB with just running the runserver command.

Comment: Like @Daniel Roseman said, sqlite3 might be the easiest way unless I use RDS

Comment: @Jay Depends. It takes a little bit to set up and is free if you stay under the free tier limit. SQLite has its purpose too, but if you have 5 people working concurrently and locally, you won't see changes. If everyone is connected to RDS and running queries, you will see changes in realtime.

Comment: Gotta have some time to think of that ! Thank you for giving me ideas